# Org-mode hide tags in agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Maybe this is weird, but I don't like how much my tags fill up the side of my org-agenda. This is especially true after I use `org-agenda-filter-by-tag` to filter down to a specific tag. For example, once I've applied a filter to see only `WORK` tasks, I'd like to not have the `WORK` tag show in the agenda view. Is there a way to hide the `:WORK:` text without hiding items with the `WORK` tag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The variable you want is `org-agenda-hide-tags-regexp`

> Regular expression used to filter away specific tags in agenda views.
>   This means that these tags will be present, but not be shown in the agenda
>   line.  Secondary filtering will still work on the hidden tags.
>   Nil means don’t hide any tags.

A typical setting is `(setq org-agenda-hide-tags-regexp "tag1\\|tag2\\|tags3")` to hide `tag1`, `tag2` and `tag3` in the agenda.

I often add

```
(org-agenda-hide-tags-regexp
           (concat org-agenda-hide-tags-regexp "\\|sometag")
```

to agenda searches for "sometag" since it is guaranteed to be on everything and I don't need to see it.

Comment: This fixes the agenda view from being totally ugly when you decrease the window's width with `visual-line-mode` enabled. Thanks!

Comment: `(setq org-agenda-hide-tags-regexp (regexp-opt '("tag1" "tag2" "tag3")))` might be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, there's also

```
(setq org-agenda-remove-tags t)
```

Which will hide all tags from headings, i.e. Org Agenda items.